# How to override APK output directory with Gradle 7.3.3 and Android Gradle Plugin 7.2.0?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'd like to override the APK output directory (not the file name, just the directory), but none of the existing Stack Overflow examples work with the current version of Android Studio, Android Gradle Plugin, and Gradle. Apparently all ways to override output path are now read-only.

So is the ONLY way to do this now via a post-build COPY of the file from the build/intermediates directory?